# Replace last characters of a string with its entire elements

Tags: r

I have an element in my dataframe which I want to modify.
I have a column with the following type of values

```
https://mns-xyz-eu.abc.com/ccs/proposal?action=view&proposalId=12345
```

I want to replace the entire string with just the last 5 characters (i.e)
Replace the entire character string with 12345 in this case.

How do I achieve this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `substr(string, nchar(string) - 4, nchar(string))`

Comment: Works fine.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is using [a positive look behind](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#look-arounds) using `stringr::str_extract`

```
str_extrct('https://mns-xyz-eu.abc.com/ccs/proposal?action=view&proposalId=12345', 
           '(?<=proposalId\\=)\\d+')
#Simple option
str_extract('https://mns-xyz-eu.abc.com/ccs/proposal?action=view&proposalId=12345', '\\d+')
```